# Run a PApplet in Max/msp

Tags: java, processing, max-msp-jitter

I try to get a processing PApplet to be initialized from Max.
I can create the Applet but i can't get it to run.
I can create a java Frame so my guess is that a PApplet should be possible.

Here is what i have know:

```
public class PAppletInMax extends MaxObject {

    public static class Test {

        Test() {
            // this is to have a message in Max console
            post("construct Test");

            // create the Processing sketch
            MaxTest_01 mt_01 = new MaxTest_01();
            // call main
            // here is where it goes wrong
            //mt_01.main(new String[]{});

            // this crashes max
            //mt_01.runSketch(new String[]{}, mt_01);
            //PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{}, mt_01);
        }


    }


    public PAppletInMax() {

        /*
        // this works
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
         */
        Test t = new Test();

    }


}
```

It would be really nice if someone could help. Cause once it works it's so much easier cause OSC won't be needed anymore for communication.

Comment: First off: OOOoooooooo this looks exciting. Second: don't post duplicates (you posted this an hour before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442103/papplet-not-appearing)

Comment: Maybe you need to access the internal Frame of the PApplet ? I also know that Frame isn't imported by default as of v2+ anymore though...

Comment: I'm in a hurry that's hence the duplicate, and it's not really a duplicate, the code in the other one is totally different.
I'm a bit further now. I can get a processing window for example. But i can't get OpenGl to work. I keep getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ` and I did so many attempts on `max.dynamic.jar.dir` and `max.dynamic.class.dir` but no luck. I'm getting a bit sick of it.

Comment: Fair enough, on closer look I see that they are not duplicates... sorry about that.

Comment: Have you asked a new question about the OpenGL embed ?

Comment: I asked on the max forum, http://cycling74.com/forums/topic/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javaxmediaopenglglexception but no luck yet.